# suddenly xcode uitablewview keyboard covers textfields

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

general question.

**Environment:** XCode 7.3.1 (using swift), iOS 9.3, iPhone 6 (updated), iPhone simulators through XCode.

**Usecase:** UITableView with multiple static rows. Almost each row has a UITextField inside to be edited. Normally (for the last week), once one started editing a text-field, the input keyboard would slide up, and the TableView would scroll-up accordingly if necessary (to show the editable text-field). This has worked fine till today. As of today, the TableView does not scroll up anymore and the TextField/s is/are therefore covered by the input-keyboard.

Another thing - this occurs on each TableView through the entire app - I was wondering therefore if it could be a global thing in the settings.

The code is long so I am not adding it to the question here yet.

**Question:** Did anybody encounter a similar problem?

Thanks in advance!

b.

**Added 3:53 PM Friday, June 24, 2016 (PDT)**

So I uploaded a simple [XCode project](https://github.com/nmrbrt/XCode-TableViewController-with-TextField) to exemplify my use case. So click the "Item" button in the upper right corner and you will get to the TableViewController with the TextField in one of the lower table-rows. In this project, once you select that row, you will see a PickerView sliding up, while the TableView sliding as well to keep the TextField visible.

Now my problem is, that in my *other* project, this is not working anymore, the PickerView slides up and covers the TextField, the TextField does not slide up and the UX is just bad.

Hope anyone has an idea what could help me out here.

Thanks again.
b.

Comment: Did you not write the code for sliding the text fields up? You may have deleted that. I don't think ios provides built- in mechanism to automatically change view's frame on clicking in textfield's editing rect

Comment: @Akshansh, haven't written any code for sliding the TableView up, at any point in the project. Thee TableViewController does that automatically. Maybe I should've mentioned that I'm using the controller. And it did work till today, so I'm 100% sure it worked ^^.